# read file and send data to yml file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i read multipe file and i try to get data in yaml file,  but i dont know why i get nothing  in my yaml file .

Do you have an idea where i can make a mistake ?

```
a = array.size
i = 0

array.each do |f|
  while i < a
    puts array[i]
    output = File.new('/home/zyriuse/documents/Ruby-On-Rails/script/Api_BK/licence.yml', 'w')
    File.readlines(f).each do |line|
      output.puts line 
      output.puts line.to_yaml
      #output.puts YAML::dump(line)
    end
    i += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `array` - I assume this is array of files? And more interesting - why do you have `while i < a` there? It looks completely unnecessary.

Comment: yes it's array of my file ! i have a loop because i have a lot of file and i need to print the name of each file above .

Comment: But you are already looping over it using each. Code above will output all the files for every single file. I think this should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems...

1. You are initializing i to zero too early... when you process the
   first file 'f' you process JUST that first file as many times as you
   have files in the array, but for all following files i is now always >= a so you're not          doing anything with them.
2. You are doing File.new in every iteration of 'f' so you are wiping out your last iteration.

This might work better...

```
output = File.new('licence.yml', 'w')
array.each do |f|
    puts f
    File.readlines(f).each do |line|
      output.puts line
      output.puts line.to_yaml
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answear that's almost work now . i have one more problem  when i execute the script i get this in my yml file --- "  'Product-Name' => 'testInstance',\n"
--- "  'Registered-To' => 'testInstance',\n"

Comment: do you have an idea why i get --- and  \n" at the end of line ?

Comment: The '---' is what separates files.  In your example every line is a separate file.  Maybe you want to do this instead? `output.puts File.read(f).to_yaml`  instead of the readlines loop.

Comment: Glad I could help!  If you accept the answer, that will earn me points and enough points on stack overflow means I become irresistible to girls, so please mark the answer as accepted, if you want, I'd appreciate it. :)